# Can you activate Don't Starve purchased from GOG on Steam?

Tags: steam, dont-starve, gog

Is it possible to activate the game [Don't Starve bought from gog.com](http://www.gog.com/gamecard/dont_starve) in a Steam account or they are separate serial keys?

Comment: Considering GoG is completely DRM free I'd be very surprised if they even had serial keys.

Comment: Actually GoG purchases usually include steam keys.  I can't verify about Don't Starve specifically, though.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No.

It has nothing to do with serial keys, though. Even if GOG is DRM free, they often supply a serial key with their games. This is for your convenience. Should GOG one day go bust, you still have your serial key – which is your unique code, or "proof of purchase", if you will.

This should not be confused with DRM, though. DRM simply put limitations on how the game can be copied or transferred. A game with no DRM can still ask you to enter a serial key for a number of reasons.

A serial key should not be confused with a Steam activation key either. It's a separate concept. If you buy the game from a retailer, or from the developer directly, they will often let you activate it on Steam, so that it is connected to your account.

Some times, they may also give you a gift code for that specific game on GOG or other game platforms.

What you will not see, however, is Steam providing GOG codes or vice versa. The reason for this, is because they are competitors. It would be similar to buying a gift certificate at the Adidas store, which you can use at the Nike store – or Google Play versus the Apple Appstore. They would be a) cutting away the profit from their competitor and b) leading customers to the competition.

**HOWEVER!**
In some cases, Steam accepts the regular serial key as the activation key, but that does not include Don't Starve. You can see the list of games which accept third party keys here: https://support.steampowered.com/kb_article.php?ref=7480-WUSF-3601

Comment: Don't Starve not being on that list actually means nothing. There's no Trackmania Canyon and no FasterThanLight on that list either.
However I purchased both games outside of Steam (Trackmania years ago on the Maniaplanet site, FTL some months ago on the humble store), and they come with a key, which is redeemable on Steam. Also if you purchase Don't Starve on its official website, it also goes through the humble store, and you will get a key, which can (but doesn't must) be activated on Steam! Still not sure, if you get the same key on gog.com.
I'm just trying to find that out ...

Comment: I was under the impression that all humble bundle purchases used steam as the delivery mechanism. Ergo, one should expect those keys to work.